# How can i verify that one string appears before a nother string in a file in C#?

Tags: c#, string, file

this is the file i would like to examine, i would like to know wethear "str1" appaers before "str2" in this txt file:

***file.txt***

```
aaa
aa
aa
aaa
a
a
aa
str1
aa
aa
a
aaa
aa
a
aaa
aaa
aa
str2
aa
a
a
aa
aaa
...
```

i am looking for a good algorithem to use on a number of files containing hundreds of lines!
p.s. i don't have source code yet, i'm still in the planing phase.

thanks.

Comment: Please read [faq] and [ask] please..

Comment: please show some source code... what have you tried ? what exactly is not working ?

Comment: BTW, is that c# or Java? you have tagged both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check

```
 if(str.indexOf("str1") != -1 && str.indexOf("str2") != -1 && str.indexOf("str1") < str.indexOf("str2"))
    return true;
```

Comment: Isn't that a few too many calls to `str.IndexOf`?

Comment: `int str1Index = str.indexOf("str1"); int str2Index = str.indexOf("str2"); if(str1Index != -1 && str2Index != -1 && str1Index < str2Index) return true;` will be better, obviously